# How to run a JavaScript code after selecting a text using the Firefox Add-On SDK?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to create a Firefox add-on using the online Add-On SDK.

What I want to do is to run a piece of JavaScript code when I select a text, i.e. as soon as the selection of a text is finished my code should be run.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the `selection` module.  Try something like this in your add-on:

```
var selection = require("selection");
selection.on('select', 
             function() {
               // run your code here with selection.text
               console.log(selection.text);
             });
```

The above should be called after you make a text selection and then you can do something with it using the `selection.text` reference.

See more info in the docs, here:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.7/packages/addon-kit/selection.html